# After binding using Objective Sharpie Protocol Methods are not getting invoked in xamarin.iOS

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, protocols, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

I have few issues with Binding using Objective sharpie.I am binding `IndoorAtlas` iOS native sdk with Xamarin.ios.

Issue is while Implementing Protocols methods as those are not getting invoked. Do we need to handle it in special way?

I am attaching API defination file and Implementation file.

```
// @protocol IALocationManagerDelegate 
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface IALocationManagerDelegate
{
    // @optional -(void)indoorLocationManager:(IALocationManager * 
    _Nonnull)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray * _Nonnull)locations;
    [Export("indoorLocationManager:didUpdateLocations:")]
    void DidUpdateLocations(IALocationManager manager, IALocation[] locations);


    // @optional -(void)indoorLocationManager:(IALocationManager * 
    _Nonnull)manager didEnterRegion:(IARegion * _Nonnull)region;
    [Export("indoorLocationManager:didEnterRegion:")]
    void DidEnterRegion(IALocationManager manager, IARegion region);
}

// @interface IALocationManager : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface IALocationManager
{
     [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
     [NullAllowed]
     IALocationManagerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

     // @property (readwrite, nonatomic, weak) id<IALocationManagerDelegate> 
     _Nullable delegate;
     [NullAllowed, Export("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Weak)]
     NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

////ViewController --Calling delegate methods

```
[Export("indoorLocationManager:didUpdateLocations:")]
public void DidUpdateLocations(IALocationManager manager , IALocation[] locations)
{
    IALocation loc = locations[locations.Length - 1];
    if (mFloorPlan != null)
    {
        CoreGraphics.CGPoint cg = mFloorPlan.CoordinateToPoint(loc.Location.Coordinate);
        this.map.Center = cg;
    }
}

[Export("indoorLocationManager:didEnterRegion:")]
public  void DidEnterRegion(IALocationManager manager, IARegion region)
{
    if (region.Type != ia_region_type.FloorPlan)
        Console.WriteLine("Region Changed to {0} " + region.Identifier);
    else
    {
        FetchFloorPlan();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Did the binding project build successfully?  2. It seems like you use weakDelegate , did you set it?

Comment: @ColeXia Yes binding project is building fine with no errors or issues. I am using weak Delegate and it is set  weak in API definition.

Comment: Did you assign the current viewcontroller to  weak delegate, `IALocationManager.WeakDelegate = this`

Comment: @ColeXia Perfect !! Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to assign the viewcontroller to the weak delegate.

```
IALocationManager manager = new IALocationManager();
manager.WeakDelegate = this;
```